# Automate detection of start and end row number of phrases

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = data.frame(main_name = c("google","yahoo","google","amazon","yahoo","google"),
                volume = c(32,43,412,45,12,54))
```

I would like to sort it accordind to main_name, example

Aiming to know from which start row there is the specific phrase until which one in order to use it into a for loop.

```
main_name volume
amazon     45
google     32
google     412
google     54
yahoo      43
yahoo      12
```

In there any "auto" to make need without the need to know the specific phrase. Just to check if it is changed and know the start and end row number?

```
amazon [1]
google [2:4]
yahoo  [5:6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse`:

```
df%>%
   arrange(main_name)%>%
   mutate(row=row_number())%>%
   group_by(main_name)%>%
   summarise(start=first(row),
             end=last(row))%>%
   mutate(res=glue::glue("[{start}:{end}]"))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  main_name start   end res  
  <fct>     <int> <int> <chr>
1 amazon        1     1 [1:1]
2 google        2     4 [2:4]
3 yahoo         5     6 [5:6]
```

Comment: Thank you it works. Is it possible to extract also the full sorted dataframe?

Comment: `df%>%  arrange(main_name)%>%  mutate(row=row_number())`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative base R solution using `rle`

```
with(rle(as.character(df$main_name)), setNames(mapply(
    function(x, y) sprintf("[%s:%s]", x, y),
    cumsum(lengths) - lengths + 1, cumsum(lengths)), values))
# amazon  google   yahoo
#"[1:1]" "[2:4]" "[5:6]"
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
"main_name volume
amazon     45
google     32
google     412
google     54
yahoo      43
yahoo      12", header = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `base R` option

```
with(df, tapply(seq_along(main_name), main_name, FUN = 
  function(x) do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = "[%d:%d]", as.list(range(x))))))
#  amazon  google   yahoo 
# "[1:1]" "[2:4]" "[5:6]"
```