# Create different dataframes using the range of rows

Tags: r

From a dataset like an example here:

```
df = data.frame(main_name = c("google","yahoo","google","amazon","yahoo","google"),
                volume = c(32,43,412,45,12,54))
```

We create a range [list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52950374/10434919):

```
library(tidyverse)

df%>%
   arrange(main_name)%>%
   mutate(row=row_number())%>%
   group_by(main_name)%>%
   summarise(start=first(row),
             end=last(row))%>%
   mutate(res=glue::glue("[{start}:{end}]"))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  main_name start   end res  
  <fct>     <int> <int> <chr>
1 amazon        1     1 [1:1]
2 google        2     4 [2:4]
3 yahoo         5     6 [5:6]
```

If we use the range list how is it possible to create different dataframes for every group.

Example:
df_amazon

```
main_name volume
amazon     45
```

df_google

```
main_name volume
google     32
google    412
google     54
```

df_yahoo

```
main_name volume
yahoo     43
yahoo     12
```

Comment: `split(df, df$main_name)`

Comment: `ls_df <- split(df, df$main_name)` gives you a list of data frames. To get the one for `amazon`, just use `ls_df$amazon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the plyr library:

```
library(plyr)
dfs <- dlply(df, .(main_name), data.frame)
> dfs[[1]]
  main_name volume
1    amazon     45
> dfs[[2]]
  main_name volume
1    google     32
2    google    412
3    google     54
> dfs[[3]]
  main_name volume
1     yahoo     43
2     yahoo     12
```